# Whats the best way to find the execution cost of a function

Tags: solidity, remix

I am interested to analyze the execution cost of the function by considering the best practice to adopt, because of that I used bytes32 rather than String which decrease the execution cost of the function from infinite to finite.

I am eager to know whats the best way to find the accurate gas execution cost. I compile the same code 2-3 times in remix and sometimes it gives me the different execution gas cost. Like for below function sometimes it gives me

```
    Execution cost: 624gas
```

and sometimes

```
    Execution cost: 454 gas.
```

The function is below which simply return the length of an array.

```
    function totalLoans() public view returns (uint){
    return(allLoansData.length);
    }
```

1) Does the difficulty parameter also impact the execution gas cost? 
2) Is there any way that we find the ideal gas cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gas cost for the same function may be different depending on the state of the contract. I had asked a question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26535/why-transaction-cost-for-same-function-differs-even-though-content-of-function-i) which will give you an idea on what factors gas depends on.

The best way I know to estimate Gas is to use [estimate gas](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas) method. Since extra gas is returned in most cases ( not when tx fails because of assert statement), it is advised to send higher gas price than estimated. Extra gas send will be refunded.